# Extract sublist from list in Python

Tags: python, list

how can I extract for example [['A', '123'], ['A', '456']] from mylist if I filtered by 'A'?

```
mylist = [['A', '123'],
 ['A', '456'],
 ['B','847'],
 ['B','677']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to achieve the results you want.

```
mylist = [['A', '123'],
 ['A', '456'],
 ['B','847'],
 ['B','677']]
letter = 'A'
# Using list comprehension
print([l for l in mylist if l[0] == letter])
# Using filer function 
print(list(filter(lambda l: l[0] == letter, mylist)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a code for you.

```
mylist = [['A', '123'],
          ['A', '456'],
          ['B', '847'],
          ['B', '677']]

output = [lst for lst in mylist if 'A' in lst]
print(output)
```

Or you can use this code;

```
output = [lst for lst in mylist if 'A' == lst[0]]
```